# JavaScript Spec - Relevant vs Surrounding Agent

Tags: javascript, html, specifications, ecmascript-next, language-specifications

Reading through the JavaScript and related specifications, these two concepts appear:

- **[Relevant agent](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#relevant-agent)** (HTML)
- **[Surrounding agent](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#surrounding-agent)** (ES)

Some of the spec uses both. For example, in the steps of [4.2.2.5 Signaling slot change](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#signaling-slot-change):

> *Append slot to slot’s **relevant agent**’s signal slots.*

and then a bit further, into step 2:

> *If the **surrounding agent**’s mutation observer microtask queued is true, then return.*

Are these concepts the same, in this case? Are they the same in all cases, from HTML's perspective?

Comment: HTML's _relevant-agent_ === ECMA's _execution-context_ in which that code is relevant. HTML's _surrounding-agent_ === ECMA's outer closure (outer _execution-context_).

Comment: Agent is [defined by ECMA](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#agent) [and is adopted by HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#agents-and-agent-clusters) - The term is synonymous in both respects.

Comment: What's confusing is ECMA says ".. the specification level execution objects held within the agent: the running execution context, the execution context stack, and the Agent Record's fields..." which implies agent contains execution-context, meaning they are distinct concepts/objects.

Comment: There are multiple agents. The surrounding-agent is an agent that acts somewhat like a container or marshaller of other agents. The current-execution-context (carefully chosen term) - is an agent within a surrounding-agent. There can also me many agents running concurrently within that surrounding agent. As I understand it, is the surrounding agent's task to present all that complexity as the single thread that the runtime sees.

Comment: Is it one concrete, top-level, surrounding-agent? Or is that agent only symbolically acting as the 'surrounding-agent' with respect to other agents by virtue of how its execution contexts are accessed?

Comment: That's up to Google, Mozilla, Apple, etc. I would avoid trying to interpret the text of the Specs as gospel. They are recommendations. The details are up to the developers. If you want to see how WebKit and V8 interact, go scour the Chromium source code. That's where you'll find the answer to the previous question.